# Want to find specific pattern, without knowing the words it contains in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

Using grep in bash

```
    Sylvester,Stallone,+42 6944789099
    Tommy, Lee Jones,+37 6923441223
    Jean Claude,Van Damme,+44 6977654322
    Jose Maria,de Santo Agostinho,+30 6936130089
    Chuck, Norris, +30 6987543212
    Chuck,Norris,+32 6944221234
    Chuck1, Norris, +32 6944221234
```

I have this file , and i want to find the lines where there is only whitespace in the phone number, how do i grep this desired pattern? For example the grep result should yield

```
Sylvester,Stallone,+42 6944789099
Chuck,Norris,+32 6944221234
```

EDIT : I want to find the lines that contain exactly one space, and that space MUST be between the country code(ex. +42) and the number itself(6944789000)

Comment: Because there is space in after Chuck1,

Comment: It's still completely not clear what you are meaning.

Comment: I will edit the post then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier with `awk` without using any regex:

```
awk 'NF==2' file

Sylvester,Stallone,+42 6944789099
Chuck,Norris,+32 6944221234
```

- By default `awk` splits fields on whitespaces
- By using condition `NF==2` we print a row that has 2 fields or a single whitespace.

If you specifically want to find lines with space between digits then use:

```
grep -P '^\S+\d+ \d+$' file

Sylvester,Stallone,+42 6944789099
Chuck,Norris,+32 6944221234
```

Or by using POSIX classes:

```
grep -E '^[^[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+$' file
```